# How can I make sure that the port I want to use is always available (i.e. not in use)?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp, datagram

Is there a way to force-free ports? The port is passed through args[].
I'm trying to build a server app that waits for UDP packets from multiple devices, so I wan't to make sure that it will always listen to the appropriate port. The data from the packets is to be processed and the results to be written in a DB. I'm using a while(true) loop to keep it listening for new packets. Is it possible that I might have concurrency issues when multiple devices (say 2000) send at once? Is there any other way than using while(true)? Any suggestions?

EDIT (it may not be right on topic)
I'm using these methods to convert signed twos complements of 2 bytes and 4 bytes length. I couldn't find a more simple way...

```
public static Long twosComp16(String str) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Long num = Long.valueOf(str, 16);

        int fix = 65536;

        if (num > (fix/2))
            return num - fix;
        else return num;
    }
    public static Long twosComp32(String str) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Long num = Long.valueOf(str, 16);

        long fix = 4294967296L;

        if (num > (fix/2))
            return num - fix;
        else return num;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't think you can force free a port. And anyway, that's up to the user. Try to not make choices for the user; ask him/her instead. What makes you think your app is more important than the other one running on that port? ;)
2. `while(running)`
3. If you're going to have heavy processing, make your server spawn a thread for each client instead of having only one processing and the others waiting.

Comment: Well, I don't think the processing is heavy, it mostly consists of finding certain bytes on the packet and getting their values as int or long (I'm working with GPS parameters like lat, long, alt, speed, timestamp, etc). And after this returning an ACK packet to the device.

Comment: Even so, if you got thousands of clients you can get into trouble. Anyway, usually it's better to spawn a thread for each client. Like said in spanish: *"it's better to prevent than to cure".*

Comment: I guess the max number of threads would depend on the hardware, so if I'm planning to use the app with, say 10'000, uncorrelated clients that send packets periodically, it would set some requirements for the machine it will be hosted on, right?

Comment: Actually I don't think there's any limit in the number of threads set by the hardware. But if there are too many the system will run out of memory or will run too slow, even crash. Also after returning an ACK, you kill the thread, so I don't think in a given moment you will have too much threads running if the processing is fast as you said. The hardware requirements are obviously dependant on what load you got. It's better to do some testing with increasing clients before to see how it performs for a given number of clients, and make the decision after this.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure about the speed. I'm just guessing it is fast, but for convenience (and from lack of knowledge since I've just started with java) I convert the packet payload to a string, the string to hex array and then I use the hex chars to do the calculations/conversions... I also find it easier to compose the ACK by using hex notation. I believe there's a faster way that I don't know yet.

Comment: Wow that would be an **AWFUL** way to do it (in any language...). Why convert to string and then the string to hex? Makes no sense. If you want to parse UDP packets, you don't have to convert them into strings (why would you do so?). Also you don't need to build the UDP ACK packet. [There are libraries for that](http://code.google.com/p/sjpcap/).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to force-free ports

No, because what would happen if two programs both demanded a port to be free? Ultimately the second program to want the port must be unsatisfied.

Comment: Then I'll have to pre set the ports in the code manually. I have used ports 5556 and 5558 hardcoded in the app and had no problems so far.